# Clear task list in the Earth Engine command line tool

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to reduce the output which is printed to the terminal when I run:

```
earthengine task list
```

Is there some way to clear the task list in the earthengine command line tool?

**UPDATE**

I don't know whether the earthengine task list can be cleared. However, the output which is printed to the terminal can easily be reduced.

This command (unix systems only) will only print the first 5 tasks:

`earthengine task list | head -n 5`;

while this command will print the last 5 tasks:

`earthengine task list | tail -n 5`

Comment: This question is unclear. Do you want only a subset of tasks (say 10 tasks) to be listed rather than all tasks to be listed when you type `earthengine task list` or do you want to clear all the tasks in your earthengine queue? Please update the question to be as specific as possible.

Comment: @kkrao, cheers, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is a way to cancel all tasks pending in the queue.
Use `earthengine task cancel all`.